# How to prevent JScrollPane from automatically scrolling down?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I am using a `JScrollPane` which contains inside it a `JTextArea`. The problem is when the `JTextArea` is populated with a lot of text, the `JScrollPane` automatically scrolls down. What property should I set on the `JScrollPane` to avoid this automatic scrolling down? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the JScrollPane is decorating a text component, it will automatically scroll to the bottom, but after it loads calling [setCaretPosition(0)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition%28int%29) on your text component will cause it to scroll to the top.

However, if it's not a text component, you can also alter the viewport like this:

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition(new Point(0,0));
```

Comment: Great answer! Is there no way this can be achieved by setting a property on the JScrollPane itself?

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer with the info that I needed.